# .NET application with SQLLocalDB performance on Atom based windows 8 tablet

Tags: wpf, windows-8

A customer is interested in having a small data collection/quote calculation application running on tablets for its sales people.

Does anyone have any experience with running .NET WPF applications using SQL LocalDB on a Windows 8 tablet with an Intel Atom processor?

Are there any performance issues that we need to be aware of before we start heading down this track?

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: Did you ever pursue this? I am looking at doing something similar.